# php Qiwi p2p - выдает ошибку класса

Tags: php, qiwi, p2p

Не могу создать выставление счетов, выдает ошибку

Код:

```
  <?php
    const SECRET_KEY = '*';
    /** @var \Qiwi\Api\BillPayments $billPayments */
    $billPayments = new Qiwi\Api\BillPayments(SECRET_KEY);
    $billId = $billPayments->generateId(); // Генерируем billId для работы сервисов qiwi
    $lifetime = $billPayments->getLifetimeByDay(0.01); // Cколько будет жить счет для оплаты, по стандарту 24 часа
    $fields = [
    'amount' => 1.00,
    'currency' => 'RUB',
    'comment' => 'test',
    'expirationDateTime' => $lifetime,
    ];
    /** @var \Qiwi\Api\BillPayments $billPayments */
    $response = $billPayments->createBill($billId, $fields);
    print_r($response);
?>
```

Ошибка:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Qiwi\Api\BillPayments' not found in H:\OSPanel\domains\php\creat-payment.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in H:\OSPanel\domains\php\creat-payment.php on line 5
```

Все было установлено через composer:
[image]

Comment: `require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';`?

Comment: @Hemeon Сначала напишите в консоли в корне `composer dump-autoload`